# read a file into a list [prolog]

Tags: list, io, prolog

I have log entries which include 4 different terms.

```
log(name1,surname1,street1,Belgium).
log(name2,surname2,street2,Germany).
log(name3,surname3,street3,France).
log(name4,surname4,street4,France).
```

I saved this into loginfo.pl. I could manage to read these from input file (loginfo.pl) however i could not collect all in a "list".After that i need to filter it by using condition " the country begin with the letter 'F'.

So at the end i want to get

```
[log(name3,surname3,street3,France),log(name4,surname4,street4,France)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`consult/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=consult/1) to load the facts contained in the file in the prolog KB.

Use [`atom_chars/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atom_chars/2) to split an atom to its characters.

Use [`findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3) to collect multiple solutions to a goal.

Example:

```
?- [loginfo].
?- findall(log(A,B,C,D), (log(A, B, C, D), sub_atom(D, 0, 1, _, 'F')), Result).
Result = [log(name3, surname3, street3, 'France'), log(name4, surname4, street4, 'France')].
```

`[loginfo]` is a shorthand for `consult(loginfo)`.

Also, if you don't like to repeat yourself:

```
?- findall(X, (X=log(_, _, _, D), X, sub_atom(D, 0, 1, _, 'F')), Result).
Result = [log(name3, surname3, street3, 'France'), log(name4, surname4, street4, 'France')].
```

Note: in your file `loginfo.pl` you should put single quotes around atoms starting with capital letters:

```
log(name1,surname1,street1,'Belgium').
log(name2,surname2,street2,'Germany').
log(name3,surname3,street3,'France').
log(name4,surname4,street4,'France').
```

Read more about prolog atoms at [Prolog Syntax - Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse2)

Comment: You should use `sub_atom(Atom, 0, _, _, 'F')` instead of `atom_chars`.

Comment: Also, prefer `setof` and `bagof` instead of `findall`.

Comment: @mescalinum Thanks for the answer. findall predicate really helped me. However if we use more complex terms like name(clara,12) what should we use instead of atom_chars?